# Using "way too...” to suggest a lack of something

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

We know that we can use "way" as an adverb of emphasis to mean "to a great degree" for example

> way too much
>   way too expensive
>   way too complicated

My question is does it make sense to use it in such way:

> Life is way too short.

I ask because the other adjectives are refereng to excess of something, but "short" is refering to a lack of something.

And if not , what is an alternative to it to mean the same here?

Comment: As you said, it just emphasizes. You could very well be "way too short" or "way too tall".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Life is *way too* short.

is perfectly acceptable, as is

> The kids grow up **way too** fast, in the blink of an eye.
>   This movie is **way too** long, I'm dying of boredom.
>   That skirt is **way too** short, it's more like a belt.